# Eclipse RCP App: How can I prompt the user to set the workspace

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, workspace

I want my `RCP` app to always prompt the user for the workspace location. I can specify a default location either with the `-data` arg in `eclipse.ini` or the `osgi.instance.area.default` property in `configuration/config.ini`. But I don't want the user to have to know about and edit either of these files to change the workspace location.

Setting the preference `Prompt for workspace on startup` has no effect. I launch the app in a clean workspace, with no `-data` arg or `osgi.instance.area.default` property set, and it creates a `workspace` folder in the current directory, and does not prompt to select a location.

I use a copy of the `IDEApplication` class for my application. I see that in line 188 which is one of the first lines run after `start()`, the platform location is already set, and this prevents the dialog from showing. I don't know why it's already set before even trying to launch the UI, and setting the preference has no effect. (I verified in `configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` that `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true`).

I tried re-setting the location by adding

```
instanceLoc = instanceLoc.createLocation(instanceLoc, null, false);
```

at the beginning of `checkInstanceLocation()`. This enables the workspace chooser dialog to come up, but setting the location this way has no effect on what the app actually uses for its instance area when it launches.

I thought that maybe some `earlyStartup` code in my app may be interfering, as I read that if you access the preferences too soon you can prevent the workspace chooser from opening. So I commented out the few `earlyStartup` declarations I had, and still I can't get the workspace chooser dialog to show.

Comment: It might be picking up a saved location. The initial location is set in the `buildLocation` method of `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.location.EquinoxLocations` so try tracing through that.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that an OSGI service I provide is accessing the ResourcesPlugin. When I remove the lazy activation policy for the plugin of the bundle that provides the service, the workspace chooser loads. But now my service does not get injected (I'm using declarative services to provide and consume it). I tried a higher start level for the services bundle, and that didn't help. How can I either delay the start of the service or make the service available without a lazy activation of its bundle?

Comment: NM. Seems I didn't try a high enough start level. Default is 4, and I had tried 5. It works with 7 or higher. I guess I should use 10? Is there a way to determine precisely what I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that some classes loaded as dependencies of my OSGI service were accessing the class `ResourcesPlugin`, which causes the workspace location to be set immediately. Since this was happening before the workspace chooser dialog was launched, the location used was the value of the -data arg if specified, otherwise `$(pwd)/workspace`.

I tried resolving the issue by adjusting the start level of my service plug-in. With a start level of 7 or higher, the workspace chooser dialog was no longer pre-empted. However, the service did not work properly then. After numerous unsuccessful attempts to make the service work properly with a custom start level, I abandoned that approach and re-worked my code so the reference to `ResourcesPlugin` occurs later in the application startup process. Specifically, I moved it to the `postWindowOpen` method of my custom `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` implementation.